# How to focus the list of songs in iTunes after typing the search query?

Tags: itunes, keyboard

Is there any way in iTunes to move the focus from the search query to the list of songs?

I just typed something, the list of songs got updated and I'd like to play the first (or any song) from the list so I'd like to use my keyboard to navigate through the results.

[image]

Comment: tab tab, then up and down arrows work here for version 12.7.3

Comment: I see though that focus is not always shown as such, even though the list is in focus.

Comment: Also depending on your settings in System Preferences > Shortcuts > Full Keyboard access (what setting do you use?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Full Keyboard Access set to "Text boxes and lists only" in System Preferences, press
<kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd>, then the list is in focus and you can use the up/down arrows to navigate.
(even if the focus is not visible at first, which seems wrong)

With Full Keyboard Access set to "All controls",
<kbd>tab</kbd> through to "Songs", then "Library", then <kbd>tab</kbd> twice more and use the up/down arrows to navigate the list.
 (As in the first method above, there won't be any visible indication that the list is in focus)

Subsequently the focus should be visible.

Comment: Keyboard access is set to "All controls" but I cannot reach the list of songs so I can navigate through it using the UP/DOWN arrows. Search box ==> Tab ==> "<" Arrow ==> Tab ==> Music ==> Tab ==> Library ==> Tab ==> For you ==> Tab ... (Browse, Radio, Store) ... => Tab => Songs (the menu item on the left, not the song list). I'm using iTunes 12.7.3.46

Comment: Just to be clear, here's what happens in a GIF: https://gifyu.com/image/LDrV

Comment: Slow down, when you reach "Library" at the left column, the next tab brings focus to the downwards pointing arrow next to "Music Playlists". Tab again (just once) and just trust to be in the songs list and use the arrow key.  The focus is not visible and a leap of faith is needed.

Comment: To be clear:  where you stopped in your first comment, carry on: Songs > Tab > Library > Tab > Music Playlist's down facing arrow > Tab > Arrow key (frame 44 in the GIF you've posted)

Comment: I confirm that this works and I'm going to use this sequence of keys, but I'll still be looking for a shorter way of achieving this (as you can see, using the tab key it requires 11 tab keystrokes).

Comment: Depending on whether something is/was playing, or not (when the top middle mini player area is empty, showing the Apple symbol), going backwards with sift+tab sometimes only requires 5 keystrokes.